# Ошибка TypeError, хотя типы одинаковые

Tags: python, строки, float

Всем привет!
При запуске кода ниже выскакивает ошибка

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

для данной строки

```
if numbers[i] < mini:
```

Код:

```
import time
startt = time.time()

# Открытие файла и запись их в массив
f = open("gaz.txt", 'r')
nums = f.readline().split()
f.close()
numbers = []
for number in nums:
    numbers.append(float(number))

#Функция поиска выгоды
def benefit():
    mini = float(10 ** 10)
    maxi = float(0)
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if numbers[i] < mini:
            mini = number[i]
            index_min = i
        if numbers[i] > maxi:
            maxi = number[i]
            index_max = i
    return mini, maxi, index_min, index_max

mini, maxi, index_min, index_min = benefit()
print(mini, maxi, index_min, index_max)

print(type(numbers[1]), type(mini))
```

Для уверенности даже закомментила весь код и вывела `type(numbers[0])` и `type(mini)`, они оба `float`, но при работе кода один из них упорно превращается в строку.

Comment: Вместе с `type(n)` полезно еще печатать просто `n`, например.

Answer (score 0):

Опечатка в `mini = number[i]`. Не хватает `s` -> `mini = numbers[i]`.

PS. И инициализруйте `index_min` и `index_max` ДО цикла. Иначе в строчке с `return` могут быть проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых Вы пишите при создании переменных:

`mini, maxi, index_min, index_min = benefit()`

Т.е. создаете переменную `index_min` два раза, одну из них (судя по коду вторую) следует заменить на `index_max`.

И ещё стоит создать переменные `index_min` и `index_max` до их использования в функции, чтобы не возникло проблем.

Касательно Вашей проблемы: можно процесс создания массива чисел организовать списочным выражением:

```
# Открытие файла и запись их в массив
f = open("gaz.txt", 'r')
numbers = [float(x) for x in f.readline().split()]
f.close()
```

И тогда работающий код будет выглядеть так:

```
import time

startt = time.time()

# Открытие файла и запись их в массив
f = open("gaz.txt", 'r')
numbers = [float(x) for x in f.readline().split()]
f.close()


# Функция поиска выгоды
def benefit():
    mini = float(10 ** 10)
    maxi = float(0)
    index_min = 0
    index_max = 0
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i] < mini:
            mini = numbers[i]
            index_min = i
        if numbers[i] > maxi:
            maxi = numbers[i]
            index_max = i
    return mini, maxi, index_min, index_max


mini, maxi, index_min, index_max = benefit()
print(mini, maxi, index_min, index_max)

print(type(numbers[1]), type(mini))
```

Comment: а где у вас в ответе решается проблема из вопроса?

Comment: Согласен, подумал что проблема в цикле, а `numbers[i]` исправил машинально